# WebStorm adds `Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });` for `commonjs` modules

Tags: typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When using TypeScript service WebStorm adds the following to the output:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

it can be seen in the following output:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); <----------
var rabbit_1 = require("./rabbit");
var r = new rabbit_1.Rabbit();
r.go();
```

The `tsconfig.json` is configured like this

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",  <---------------
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false
    }
}
```

And `tsc` correctly outputs modules in `commonjs`. Why does WebStorm adds this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using a different typescript version for tsc. Since 2.2, `__esModule` is emitted for all ES6 modules. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13709